# How do I add permissions to ActiveStorage?

Tags: rails-activestorage

I'm migrating to ActiveStorage an app that is permissions sensitive.  I need to make sure files are only accessed by people with permissions, and that those permissions only last for a specified period of time.

With Paperclip, that was as easy as defining a route with a pundit authorization call:

```
def thumbnail
    authorize @record
    redirect_to @record.thumbnail.expiring_url(300)
end
```

Any call to `/record/thumbnail` would be authenticated by devise, authorized by pundit, and then redirected to S3 with an expiring url.  It's a process that worked.

Moving to ActiveStorage, my initial thought was I'd use `service_url`, but it only works if I'm using S3 -- it doesn't work in testing, it doesn't work if I'm in local development with a disk service.  The actual, 'correct' approach is to use `url_for`, or in the example above `redirect_to url_for @record.thumbnail`.

The problem is, `url_for` appears to issue a permanent url -- the url it generates is always valid, for anyone, without authentication or authorization.  More importantly, once someone has that url, I can't revoke it, I can't say it's only good for a week.  Once someone has that url, they have access to the file, forever.  (Or, presumably, at least until the file is updated).

I don't think it's a huge security flaw, but it's definitely a step backward from what was achievable using Paperclip.  Am I missing an important detail, or is this really all that's doable with ActiveStorage?

Comment: I'm puzzled, when I use image_tag(@record.thumbnail) or image_tag(url_for(@record.thumbnail) I get a url redirect that only lasts a few minutes.

What did you do to get a permanent url? Whenever I try I only get something that lasts a few minutes and cannot be cached or used with a CDN

A permanent url might be a problem for you, but it's a solution for a lot of people including me. Have you accidentally found a solution to our problems?

Comment: @JohnSmall no clue.  Maybe it's a version issue?  Maybe the links aren't good for as long as I think (though that should have caused issues with some of our apps that need the link to remain valid for a prolonged period of time, so they can reconnect downloads)

Answer (score 8):

The documentation says:

> If you need to enforce access protection beyond the security-through-obscurity factor of the signed blob references, you'll need to implement your own  authenticated redirection controller.

Which is not particularly helpful. To do this you create your own controller to serve the blobs:

```ruby
class BlobsController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveStorage::SetBlob
  before_action :authorize_blob

  def show
    expires_in ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url_expires_in
    redirect_to @blob.service_url(disposition: params[:disposition])
  end

  private

  def authorize_blob
    # Your authorization code goes here
  end
end
```

Then you will need to set up your routing:

```ruby
  get '/blobs/:signed_id/*filename' => "blobs#show", as: "service_blob"
  direct :blob do |blob, options|
    route_for(:service_blob, blob.signed_id, blob.filename, options)
  end
  resolve("ActiveStorage::Blob") { |blob, options| route_for(:blob, blob, options) }
```

Finally, you need to disable the insecure default controller so that a knowledgeable user cannot circumvent your authorization.

If you are in Rails 6.1+, you can do this by setting `config.active_storage.draw_routes` to false in your application.rb. But you will then need to make sure the rest of the ActiveStorage routes are drawn manually and there are quite a few of them. You can [view them on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/config/routes.rb).

Otherwise, you will need to add extend the controller to redirect to your new one (or just shut it down entirely). You can add the following to an initializer:

```ruby
module ActiveStorageRedirect
  def self.included(controller)
    controller.before_action :redirect_to_authenticated
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_authenticated
    redirect_to Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blob_path(@blob)
  end
end

ActiveStorage::Blobs::RedirectController.include(ActiveStorageRedirect) # For Rails >= 6.1
ActiveStorage::Blobs::ProxyController.include(ActiveStorageRedirect) # For Rails >= 6.1
# ActiveStorage::BlobsController.include(ActiveStorageRedirect) # For Rails < 6.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'd mark it as accepted, but I can't test it -- new job, no longer have access to projects where this is relevant.